# Comunication using Pipe Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe, nonblocking, thread-synchronization

[image]

Hello ! I have a little problem. I just learn multithreading and don't understand everything yet.

I have 3 threads : 1 and 2 generate a matrix random, and after every step they send like parameter by pipe matrix element . The 3-d thread compare they and write result, after that the 1-st and 2-nd tread doing next step an it is repeat again and again 5 times.

My problem : I need to synchronize all the treads for right work. This problem have something similar with producer/consumer problem , but here are 2 producers an 1 consumer.

---

```
public class Producer1 extends Thread{
    CyclicBarrier cbar;
    public Producer1(CyclicBarrier c){
        cbar=c;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    private Random generator = new Random();
    int []matrix1 = new int[1000];


    private PipedWriter out = new PipedWriter();

    public PipedWriter getPipedWriter() {
        return out;
     }

    public void run() {
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
            matrix1[i]= generator.nextInt(10)+10;
             System.out.println("matrix1["+i+"]= "+matrix1[i]);
             try {

                  out.write(matrix1[i]);
                  cbar.await();
                  sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Producer2 extends Thread{
     Random generator = new Random();
     int []matrix2 = new int[1000];
     CyclicBarrier cbar;
        public Producer2(CyclicBarrier c){
            cbar=c;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
     private PipedWriter out = new PipedWriter();

        public PipedWriter getPipedWriter() {
            return out;
         }
        public void run() {
            for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
                matrix2[i]= generator.nextInt(20)-10;
                 System.out.println("matrix2["+i+"]= "+matrix2[i]);
                 try {
                      out.write(matrix2[i]);
                      cbar.await();
                      sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
            }   
        }
}
```

---

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
     Producer1 prod = new Producer1(new CyclicBarrier(2, new Consummer(prod,prod2)));   
        // here is a problem  "prod2 cannot be resolved to a variable" 
                                                     // How can i do it work??
     Producer2 prod2 = new Producer2(new CyclicBarrier(2, new Consummer(prod,prod2)));
         CyclicBarrier cb1 = new CyclicBarrier(2, new Consummer(prod,prod2)); 

        prod.start();
        prod2.start();
    }
```

### }

```
public class Consummer extends Thread{
     private PipedReader el1;
     private PipedReader el2;


      public Consummer(Producer1 sender, Producer2 sender2) throws IOException {
        el1 = new PipedReader(sender.getPipedWriter());
        el2 = new PipedReader(sender2.getPipedWriter());
      }

    public void run() {
         try {

               while (true) {

                System.out.println("Element1 : " +  el1.read()+" Element2 : " +  el2.read());
               }
            } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

    }

}


            for example : 
i=0
1-> 10
2-> 5
3-> first is bigger =10
i++;

i=1;
1-> 3
2-> 5
3-> Second is bigger =5
i++;

i=2;
1-> 4
2-> 4
3-> both are equal = 4
i++;
.....
```

Comment: If you want to pass work from one thread to another I suggest you use an ExecutorService, it is much simpler and more functional.  Pipes are rarely used these days for passing work.

Answer (score 1):

One option that might also simplify the structure is to use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

- In `main`, create two queues, passing one each to each producer and both two the consumer
- The producers write to their queue
- The consumer reads from both queue and does its thing:

```
while (true) {
  int[] matrix1 = queue1.remove();
  int[] matrix2 = queue2.remove();
  // process the two 
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use `take()` instead `remove()` when using a `BlockingQueue`. `remove()` will throw an Exception if empty and will not block.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `barrier` to consumer and let it wait before printing like:

```
           while (true) {
            barrier.wait();
            System.out.println("Element1 : " +  el1.read()+" Element2 : " +  el2.read());
           }
```